# Javascript POST API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to create a POST API which collects data from a HTML form and POSTS it into a SQL database, except I am having some difficulty. A file called 'test.js' has been created and this is linked by way of an action to the HTML form. Yet when I click on submit on the form, nothing seems to happen. I've also tested this using Postman and nothing happens. Any input would be much appreciated! No doubt it is probably something simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Inspired Intelligence - Education</h1>
    <a href={% url 'Education:School:DTHome' %}>Design & Technology</a>
    <a href={% url 'Education:School:EnglishHome' %}>English</a>
    <a href={% url 'Education:School:MathematicsHome' %}>Mathematics</a>
    <a href={% url 'Education:School:ScienceHome' %}>Science</a>
    
    <h2>Data Sources</h2>
    <a href = {% url 'Education:School:DTData' %}> Design & Technology Data </a>
    <a href = {% url 'Education:School:EnglishData' %}> English Data </a>
    <a href = {% url 'Education:School:MathematicsData' %}> Mathematics Data </a>
    <a href = {% url 'Education:School:ScienceData' %}> Science Data </a>
    
    <h2>Data</h2>


<form action="/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data" method="POST" action=".Education/School/test.js" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="fname">Title:</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Title" name="Title"><br>
  <label for="lname">Subtitle:</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Subtitle" name="Subtitle"><br>
  <label for="lname">Body:</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Body" name="Body">
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit Data </button>
</form>

<script src=".Education/School/Javascript/test.js" type="application/json"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyPasrser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT||8000,function(){
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port ",port);
});

dbconfig = {
    
    user: "",
    password: "",
    server: "localhost",
    database: "Healthcare",
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    
}

var executeQuery = function(res,query,parameters){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("there is a database connection error -> "+err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            // create request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // Add parameters
            parameters.forEach(function(p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

            // query to the database
            request.query(query,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error while querying database -> "+err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.post("/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data", function(req, res) {
    
    var parameters = [
    { Title: 'Title', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Title},
    { Subtitle: 'Subtitle', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Subtitle},
    { Body: 'Body', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Body},
    ];
    
        var query = "INSERT INTO Healthcare.dbo.Core (Title, Subtitle, Body) VALUES ('" +req.body.Title + "', '"+req.body.Subtitle +"','"+req.body.Body +"')";
    executeQuery (res, query, parameters);
});
```

test.py

```
from javascript import require


data.executeQuery = require("test.js")

data.executeQuery(This is a test, another test, another another test)
```

Comment: Start by adding a `console.log` call at the start of the callback function you pass to `app.post`, then you can see if its being called at all.

Comment: Your `<form>` element has *two* `action` attributes.  Which one are you expecting to use?  The second one appears to have a typo.  It's also very uncommon to POST to a JavaScript file directly.  Perhaps you meant to post to a *route* in an Express `app.post()` operation?  (Which you appear to be attempting to do in the first `action` attribute?)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be executing the callback function passed into app.post. Also I deleted the second form action attribute and kept the first. Please could you clarify how to post to a route in an Express app.post() operation? I would be grateful if the goal of posting data to a sql database could be clarified.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make your code more organized and clean. Below, I've made corrections and added comments to make it clearer.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Form Submission</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Inspired Intelligence - Education</h1>
        <!-- Other parts of your HTML here -->
        
        <h2>Data</h2>
        
        <!-- I removed one of the action attributes, and kept the right one -->
        <form action="/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <!-- If you're not using Django or similar framework, remove the csrf_token line -->
          <label for="fname">Title:</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Title" name="Title"><br>
          <label for="lname">Subtitle:</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Subtitle" name="Subtitle"><br>
          <label for="lname">Body:</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Body" name="Body">
          <br>
          <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, let's make the Node.js file (test.js) more organized:

```
var express = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();

// Using the built-in middleware for parsing JSON and url-encoded form data
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Database configuration
var dbconfig = {
    user: "",
    password: "",
    server: "localhost",
    database: "Healthcare",
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
};

// Function to execute SQL queries
var executeQuery = function(res, query, parameters) {
    sql.connect(dbconfig, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Database connection error -> " + err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // Adding parameters to the SQL request
            parameters.forEach(function(p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

            // Executing the query
            request.query(query, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error while querying database -> " + err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

// Handling POST request
app.post("/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data", function(req, res) {
    var parameters = [
        { name: 'Title', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Title },
        { name: 'Subtitle', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Subtitle },
        { name: 'Body', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.Body }
    ];

    // Using parameterized query to prevent SQL injection
    var query = "INSERT INTO Healthcare.dbo.Core (Title, Subtitle, Body) VALUES (@Title, @Subtitle, @Body)";
    executeQuery(res, query, parameters);
});

// Starting the server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port ", port);
});
```

Remember:

- Run the server by executing node test.js in the terminal.
- Ensure that the action attribute in your form
  (/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data) matches the endpoint
  specified in your server code.
- Check your database configuration.
- Avoid SQL injection by using parameterized queries.
- If not using Django, remove the csrf_token from the HTML.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, this works, however it is posting NULL rather than the text i'm typing into each of the form fields. I'm sure this is probably a quick fix.

Comment: In your HTML form, you've specified the `enctype` attribute as `multipart/form-data`. This is generally used for uploading files. Since you're only sending text data, you don't need this attribute. Instead, you should use the default encoding which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Remove the `enctype` attribute from the form tag, like this: `<form action="/Education/School/DesignTechnology/Data" method="POST">`. I've updated the example to reflect this change.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you once more, however I have added in a javascript import in a python file. I would also like to have the functionality to add parameters in the python file and pass the parameters from the python file into the Javascript file. For further background info please visit https://blog.logrocket.com/exploring-jspybridge-library-python-javascript/

Comment: This would be a new question you ask using hashtag `python` and hashtag `javascript`. This is because they like to keep questions within the scope they were asked here on Stack Overflow. Also, do mention in your question you are using that library.